# SQL query with SQL variables does not work in Doctrine but works if executed manually

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I have this query, which retrieves many results if I execute it manually:

```
SELECT id, filename, path, parentId, CONCAT(path, filename) full_path
FROM (SELECT * FROM assets WHERE `type` = 'folder' ORDER BY parentId, id) assets_sorted
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(parentId, @pv)
AND LENGTH(@pv := CONCAT(@pv, ',', id))
ORDER BY LOWER(full_path)
```

When I run this through Doctrine connection, then the result is always empty.

```
/** @var Connection $con */
$con = $this->getDoctrine()->getConnection();
$folders = $con->executeQuery(
    <<<SQL
        SELECT id, filename, path, parentId, CONCAT(path, filename) full_path
        FROM (SELECT * FROM assets WHERE `type` = 'folder' ORDER BY parentId, id) assets_sorted
        WHERE FIND_IN_SET(parentId, @pv)
        AND LENGTH(@pv := CONCAT(@pv, ',', id))
        ORDER BY LOWER(full_path)
    SQL
)->fetchAll();
dump($folders);die;
```

I have tried some other variations with prepared statement and blank PDO-Connection. Results are empty. Doctrine leaves this in dev.log:

```
[2020-11-09 14:50:38] doctrine.DEBUG:     SELECT id, filename, path, parentId, CONCAT(path, filename) full_path     FROM (SELECT * FROM assets WHERE `type` = 'folder' ORDER BY parentId, id) assets_sorted     WHERE FIND_IN_SET(parentId, @pv)     AND LENGTH(@pv := CONCAT(@pv, ',', id))     ORDER BY LOWER(full_path) [] []
```

I can take the query from log, paste it into my client and it will work. It seems to me that there is an issue with the colon ":" or the "@".

Comment: What is the initial value of `@pv`? Or is it NULL to begin with?

Comment: This is weird. I have added $con->executeQuery("SET @pv = '0';"); right before the query and this works! Thank you for advise!

Comment: Because `FIND_IN_SET(parentId, NULL)` returns NULL, so the initial subquery will always find no matching rows.

Comment: OK, but why it works through native SQL client?? It is the same query.

Comment: You must have set `@pv` to some non-NULL value in the same session before running the query.

Answer (score 1):

With an initial value for @pv it worked. Code:

```
/** @var Connection $con */
$con = $this->getDoctrine()->getConnection();
$con->executeQuery("SET @pv = '0';");
$folders = $con->executeQuery(
    <<<SQL
        SELECT id, filename, path, parentId, CONCAT(path, filename) full_path
        FROM (SELECT * FROM assets WHERE `type` = 'folder' ORDER BY parentId, id) assets_sorted
        WHERE FIND_IN_SET(parentId, @pv)
        AND LENGTH(@pv := CONCAT(@pv, ',', id))
        ORDER BY LOWER(full_path)
    SQL
)->fetchAll();
```

Thanks to @bill-karwin.